# Issue displaying image in main activity

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to programmatically display an image on the main activity. Ive done this successfully on a ContentFragment before but for some reason the image is not there after a successful build.

My sample code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    ViewGroup mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) myView;

    ImageView wView = new ImageView(this);
    Drawable W = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.w);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParam =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    wView.setImageDrawable(W);                        
    imageParam.setMargins(100, 100, 0, 0);
    mainLayout.addView(wView);
    wView.setLayoutParams(imageParam);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity we inflate the view in the Activity's onCreate method by calling: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

If you want to add image to this view programmatically try to get the Activity's root view first:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

And then add your image to this view:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        ImageView wView = new ImageView(this);
        Drawable W = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.w);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageParam.setMargins(100, 100, 0, 0);
        wView.setLayoutParams(imageParam);
        wView.setImageDrawable(W);
        viewGroup.addView(wView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked exactly how I wanted it to. Also I liked how you stacked the RelativeLayout initialization. That looks a lot neater.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set its height width :

```
ImageView wView = new ImageView(this);
((ViewGroup.LayoutParams)(wView.getLayoutParams())).width = 200;
((ViewGroup.LayoutParams)(wView.getLayoutParams())).height = 200;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question but Im afraid that didn't get the image to show up. CookieMonster's implementation work but I am glad you shared your code as I will need to adjust height and width params later.